# Can I add a fourth route token in asp mvc core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-2.0

Is there a way add a fourth route token to the existing area, controller, action routes?

for example i want a routing like

```
fourthRouteValue/Area/Controller/Action
```

The app we are trying to build is so large that it will be almost impossible to properly arrange everything without it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am finding it hard understanding the routing example above. For asp.net mvc though, it is possible to create custom route templates that you can re-use in your controllers. Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Th current ASP NET Core 2.0 routes use **Area**, **Controller** and **Action** as route tokens. 

But our app is so large that a fourth token would be a very big help. And there are too many actions to go around and give routes as the as per the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for anyone who comes here later, here is how i fixed it.

I created a `RouteValueAttribute` as follows

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class RegionAttribute : RouteValueAttribute
{
    public RegionAttribute(string regionName) : base("Region", regionName)
    {
    }
}
```

Then i can use this similar to how you would specify an area

```
[Region("Region")]
[Area("Area")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and in `startup.cs`

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
         name: "main_route_region",
         template: "{region:exists}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Now the action will be accessible from `~/Region/Area/Test/Index`